# Seleccionando datos de la base de datos con Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un problema por que estoy haciendo una búsqueda de datos en `MySQL` con un `select` y un `where` así por ejemplo:

```
select * from $tabla where categoria = :categoria and ambitos = :ambitos
```

El problema es cuando quiero traer todos los datos y ya no necesito utilizar el `where`, tengo un `dropdown` donde están las categorías y otro ámbitos, pero cada uno también quisiera que tuviera todos para traer por ejemplo todos los datos de categoría y para traer todos los datos de ámbitos.

Comment: Podrías crear varias consultas *(una por cada caso que mencionas)*, ¿estás familiarizado con los procedimientos almacenados?

Comment: Tenia pensado hacer lo que dices, varias consultas por cada caso pero pense que habia una forma mas optima de hacerlo y con respecto si estoy familiarizado con procedimientos almacenados, no en realidad. como seria eso?

Comment: Aquí hay una [referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html), tendrías que investigar sobre cómo hacer procedimientos almacenados en MySQL. Por cierto ¿qué datos y estructura tiene la tabla`$tabla`? es mejor que leas **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y mejores tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Ok amigo gracias, voy a revisar el sitio que me enviaste.. Posee los siguientes datos nada fuera de lo comun, id, titulo, categoria, ambito, informacion. todos en varchar y su id en int A.Increment

Answer (score 0):

Si las tablas tienen campos parecidos puedes realizar una union y listar los resultados, o usar dos consultas y con php unir los resultados en la misma tabla.

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
```

Revisa la documentación de [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)